# $T$ induces a natural linear map $L : N/K\to M$

Tags: normed-spaces

We are given that $T$ is a continuous linear map of a normed linear space $N\to M$, $M$ is also normed linear space. $K$ be it's Kernel,  we need to show the title.

I think here is the natural mapping will be.

$L : N/K\to M, L(x+K) = T(x) $

Am I right?

But again I am not able to show that $\|T\|=\|L\|$, Thank you very much for your helpful suggestions and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. $L$ is (obviously) linear and well-defined. To compute its norm, let's denote the natural projection $N \to N/K$ by $\pi$. Then we have $T = L\pi$, hence
$$ \def\n#1{\left\|#1\right\|}\n{T} = \n{L\pi} \le \n L \n\pi \le \n L $$ 
as $\n\pi \le 1$.

On the other hand, for $x \in N$ and $\epsilon > 0$ choose $k \in \ker T$ with 
$$ \n{x+k} \le (1 + \epsilon)\n{x + K} $$
We have
\begin{align*}
  \n{L(x+K)} &= \n{Tx}\\
             &= \n{T(x+k)}\\
             &\le \n T\n{x+k}\\
             &\le \n T\n{x+K}(1 + \epsilon)
\end{align*}
Hence, 
$$ \n L \le \n T (1 + \epsilon) $$
as $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, $\n L \le \n T$.

Comment: Thanks, very nice answer, Thank you very much for your reply